# Getting multiple values from same xml column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to get the values from same xml node under same element.

Sample data:

I have to select all `<award_number>` values.

This is my SQL code:

```
DECLARE @xml XML;

DECLARE @filePath varchar(max);

SET @filePath = '<workFlowMeta><fundgroup><funder><award_number>0710564</award_number><award_number>1106058</award_number><award_number>1304977</award_number><award_number>1407404</award_number></funder></fundgroup></workFlowMeta>'

SET @xml = CAST(@filePath AS XML);

SELECT                         
    REPLACE(Element.value('award_number','NVARCHAR(255)'), CHAR(10), '') AS award_num
FROM    
    @xml.nodes('workFlowMeta/fundgroup/funder') Datalist(Element);
```

Can't change this `@xml.nodes('workFlowMeta/fundgroup/funder')`, because I'm getting multiple node values inside `funder` node.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those `<award_number>` nodes are inside the `<funder>` nodes, and there could be several `<funder>` nodes (if I understood your question correctly), you need to use two `.nodes()` calls like this:

```
SELECT                         
    XC.value('.', 'int')
FROM    
    @xml.nodes('/workFlowMeta/fundgroup/funder') Datalist(Element)
CROSS APPLY
    Element.nodes('award_number') AS XT(XC)
```

The first `.nodes()` call gets all `<funder>` elements, and then the second call goes into each `<funder>` element to get all `<award_number>` nodes inside of that element and outputs the value of the `<award_number>` element as a `INT` (I couldn't quite understand what you're trying to do to the `<award_number>` value in your code sample....)

Comment: Hi, I "plused" yours, as it was earlier than mine and is a good answer of course...

Comment: Thank you marc. its really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Your own code was very close, but

- You are diving one level to low
- You need to set a `singleton XPath` for `.value()`. In most cases this means a `[1]` at the end)

As you want to read *many* `<award_number>` elements, this is the level you have to step down in `.nodes()`. Reading these element's values is easy, once you have your hands on it:

```
SELECT                         
    REPLACE(Element.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(255)'), CHAR(10), '') AS award_num
FROM    
    @xml.nodes('/workFlowMeta/fundgroup/funder/award_number') Datalist(Element);
```

**What are you trying to do with the `REPLACE()`?**
If all `<arward_number>` elements contain valid numbers, you should use `int` or `bigint` as target type and there shouldn't be any need to replace non-numeric characters. Try it like this:

```
SELECT Element.value('text()[1]','int') AS award_num
FROM @xml.nodes('/workFlowMeta/fundgroup/funder/award_number') Datalist(Element);
```

**If marc_s is correct...**
... and you have to deal with several `<funder>` groups, each of which contains several `<award_number>` nodes, go with his approach (two calls to `.nodes()`)